# Get path to particular scheme

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, xcodeproj

I'm writing a `post_install` script in a `Podfile`, and I need to modify a particular scheme. I'm new to Ruby, so I'm sure I have many bad/non-idiomatic habits. Here's what I have:

```
post_install do |installer|
  pods_project = installer.pods_project
  scheme_filename = "BonMot.xcscheme"
  scheme = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.new File.join(pods_project.path, "xcshareddata/xcschemes", scheme_filename)
  # do stuff with scheme
end
```

How can I avoid the hardcoded `xcshareddata/xcschemes` in the middle? Or is that the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Xcodeproj::XCScheme.shared_data_dir(project_path)`

(Agreed we could have a better way to create an `Xcodeproj::XCScheme` instead directly from the `Xcodeproj::Project` instance to make this easier)

So something like this should work:

```
scheme_path = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.shared_data_dir(project.path) + 'BomMot.xcscheme'
scheme = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.new(scheme_path)
```